How to add an active class to the <li> of an active router-link in Vue3
The current Vue3 behavior is it automatically add an active class to the <a> tag generated by router-link. What if I wanted it on the parent <li> it belongs to?
Is there a fast, easy way to do it or I need to loop check it?
<ul>
    <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'Dashboard' }" class="nav-link" active-class="active"> Dashboard </router-link></li>
    <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'Login' }" class="nav-link"> Login </router-link></li>
</ul>


You could use the has pseudo class to style your li based on the a class:
li:has(a.active){
 /* your style */
}

